# How to use array of routes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm newbie with react but i saw something weird. I've got all of my routes something like below:

```
        <Main>
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/home1" component={Home1} />
          <Route exact path="/home2" component={Home2} />
          <Route exact path="/home3" component={Home3} />
          <Route exact path="/home4" component={Home4} />
          <Route exact path="/home5" component={Home5} />
          
          <Redirect from="*" to="/home" />
        </Main>
```

is there any way  to use an `array` and `map` instaed of paste another one `<Route />` component?

I think about somehting like this:

```
routes.ts
const routes = [
    { path: "/home", component: SomeComponent },
    { path: "/home2", component: SomeComponent2 },
];


indes.tsx
<Main>
    { routes.map(route => (
        <Route exact path={route.path} component={route.component} />
    ))}
</Main>
```

but i don't know how to pass new component into object in `routes` list.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: *"but i don't know how to pass new component into object in routes list."* What do you mean by that? You just add it to the array. What you have seems fine other than that A) You need a `key` on the `Route` elements, since you're rendering an array, and B) You've left off the `Redirect` after the `map` outputing the array.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Which react-router-dom version are u using? This is a code example for RRD6

```
const routes = [
  { name: "/route1", component: <ClickLabel /> },
  { name: "/route2", component: <Focus /> },
  { name: "/route3", component: <Counter /> }
];

/*--------------***/
{routes.map(({ name, component }, i) => ( 
    <Route key={i} path={name} element={component} />
))}
```

Here is example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-swartz-ikqdn?file=/src/App.js

---

If u are using RRDv5, then here is the code

```
  {/* Want to pass some dynamic props */}
  {routes.map(({ name, component }, i) => (
    <Route
      key={i}
      path={name}
      render={() => {
        return React.createElement(
          component,
          { p: "THis is the prop" },
          null
        );
      }}
    />
  ))}
  {/* Simply render a component */}
  {routes.map(({ name, component }, i) => (
    <Route key={i} path={name} component={component} />
  ))}
```